# Which .NET Core installation components to be installed on Windows?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a question about which components need to be installed on the application server for a .NET Core console application and a .NET Core web application.

I have downloaded and installed the following 2 components.

DotNetCore.1.0.1-WindowsHosting - My understanding is that this is a module that allows your .net core app to run on IIS. So this would be for a web app.

dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-003156 - My understanding is that this is the dotnet core run time and also includes the dotnet command line interface.

I assume that I would need to install the first component for a web app even if I am only targeting a net451 framework. Correct?

Now if I only target the net451 framework and not the dotnetcore framework do I
need to install the first component for a web app? I assume the answer is yes?

Now if I only target the net451 framework and not the dotnetcore framework do I need to install the second component above for either a web or console app when I deploy the app as a "portable" app, i.e. not self contained.

If I did deploy as a self contained app is it the case that I would never need to install the second component regardless of which framework I was targeting?

Answer (score 0):

WindowsHosting contains AspNetCoreModule for IIS hosting so yes you'll need that for either target framework.

No additional installs are required when targeting net451.

Self-contained apps should be by definition self-contained, but you'll want to confirm that one via testing.